# error installing VSTS 2008 SP1

Tags: .net, windows, msi, windows-server-2003

I am installing VSTS 2008 SP1 on Windows Server 2003 R2 32-bit, which has already installed with VSTS 2008 successfully before. I met with the following error (from install log, at almost the end of install progress from progress bar), any ideas what is wrong?

(IronSpigot::MsiExternalUiHandler::InstallMessageErrorHandler) Returning IDOK. INSTALLMESSAGE_ERROR [Error 1718。File C:\WINDOWS\Installer\35d33.msp Rejected by digital signature policy]

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not run into this problem with Windows Server 2008 or above, however I have had problems with large Windows Installer packages under Windows XP and 2003. Try the workarround from [KB925336](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925336):

> To work around this problem, change
>   the PolicyScope registry value to 1
>   before you try to install the package.
>   To do this, follow these steps.

That said the above has **never actually worked for me**, the second workaround on that page did though:

1. Click Start, click Run, type control admintools, and then click OK.
2. Double-click Local Security Policy.
3. Click Software Restriction Policies.
4. Under Object Type, double-click Enforcement.
5. Click All users except local administrators, and then click OK.
6. Restart the computer.

Remember to revert the changes (Delete the Software Restriction Policy, or change it All Users) when you are finished installing VSTS.

Comment: Thanks! "never actually worked for me" -- confused. You mean the 6 steps never work for you or?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't being very clear. I meant the first part of the Workarround never really worked for me, configuring the Software Restriction policy did however work. I was referencing the full Workarround for completeness.

Comment: You mean the 6 steps work for you?

Comment: Yes [This comment does not require 15 characters]

Comment: This fix might also be needed to apply SP1 to Visual Studio itself. (Painful memories of convincing system admins to drop the group policy enforcing the setting we needed to change.)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this KB Article,](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925336) the error is down to the fact that there is not enough contiguous memory for  Windows Installer to verify the msi package is correctly installed. The article provides a hot fix for server 2003, but nothing for server 2008. I would suggest ensuring there is a good amount of free memory on the server when you run the installer.

There is also a workaround to disable checking of the signature, the steps are listed [here](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/93626/you-receive-error-1718-file-filename-was-rejected-by-digital-signature-policy-when-you-attempt-to-install-a-large-windows-installer-package-or-patch-on-windows-server-2003.html).

Comment: "ot enough contiguous memory for Windows Installer to verify the msi package is correctly installed." -- confused. I monitored only a small portion memory is used from performance tab of task manager. Why still not enough memory?

Comment: Well contiguous memory would be blocks in memory that are adjacent to each other, it could be this is not available, have you tried rebooting? If that doesn't work I would suggest following the workaround just to get this installed.